# How to pass two ids from same page to the database

Tags: php, database

This is my first question posting here. So hope you don't mind any inexpert behaviour from my side. Below is my code which I hoped that when selecting the options in the drop-down menu it will show the corresponding division and hide the other. Anyway, the show-hide is working but even though two divisions have separate ids (sort=1 and sort=2) only one id (sort=0) is displayed for both divisions. Ie., only seniority-based sorting is happening in both divisions. 
How can I solve this problem? I am kind of a beginner in this field so hope you will help me. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv() {
        var ddlPassport = document.getElementById("ddlPassport");
        var dvPassport = document.getElementById("dvPassport");
        dvPassport.style.display = ddlPassport.value == "Y" ? "block" : "none";
        var dvPass = document.getElementById("dvPass");
        dvPass.style.display = ddlPassport.value == "N" ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>
<span>Sort Faculty List </span>
    <select id = "ddlPassport" onchange = "ShowHideDiv()">
        <option value="N">In Alphabetic order</option>
        <option value="Y">Based On Seniority</option>            
    </select>
<hr />

<div id="dvPass" style="display: block">
   <div style="margin:10px;">

<table id="faculty-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


    </tbody>
</table>
<?php $dept_id=1;$sort=1;?> 
</div>
</div>


<div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
   <div style="margin:10px;">

<table id="faculty-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>sl.No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


    </tbody>
</table>
<?php $dept_id=1;$sort=0;?> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the sorting? Where are the values? Neither of them is present.

Comment: Unlike Javascript, which runs in the browser, PHP is executed on the server and the output, if any, is generated before it is sent to the browser. In your case the PHP code that is present does absolutely nothing useful.